# Does WIFI allow an AP to probe clients? Even ones not connected?

Tags: ieee-802.11

I am aware that clients can send probe requests to find hidden SSID APs. Also, I've seen that clients can send probe-any requests with NULL SSID lists, to see all APs within range.

However, can APs send probe requests(or something similar) to reveal clients? If so, could this also reveal clients who are not connected to that AP?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

APs don’t send probe requests, nor do clients respond to them.

But APs ( or a controller) know (the clients that are associated with them.

Some APs can act as wireless sniffers that can scan other channels and detect other WiFi clients. They can also detect interference sources.

Comment: Do they do spectrum analysis to see other WiFi clients?

Comment: They passively listen, but I don't think they are full spectrum analyzers.